# ERRO NO FLUTTER - The method '[]' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

Estou começando com o Flutter, e me deparei com o erro

> The method '[]' was called on null.

Estou testando uma api para me retornar os dados, porem sempre recebo esse erro. O estranho é que se eu reinicio a aplicação o erro some e os dados aparecem normalmente. Esse erro acontece em todas as telas que uso na api, e em todas elas se reinicio a aplicação ou volto a tela e abro-a novamente o erro não acontece.

```dart
    List<GetItems> _item;

    Future<List<GetItems>> _getItem() async {
      List<GetItems> listItem = [];

      final response = await http.get(
          'http://192.168.1.145/crud/index.php?action=getItem&id=' + widget.id);

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var decodeJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
        decodeJson.forEach((item) => listItem.add(GetItems.fromJson(item)));
        return listItem;
      } else {
        print('connection error');
      }
    }

    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      _getItem().then((map) {
        _item = map;
      });
    }

return Scaffold(
  drawer: SideMenu(),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Top(title: _item[0].nome),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
          height: 250,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 20,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/img/' + _item[0].imagens),
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              )
          ),
       ),
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro ocorre pois quando a árvore de widgets é feita, ele tenta buildar:

```
AssetImage('assets/img/' + _item[0].imagens)
```

Entretanto o _item não é inicializado, ou seja, é null. Por isso dá erro.

Você está fazendo o fetch de dados no init state e depois dando um setState. Por que não utiliza um FutureBuilder?

```
    FutureBuilder(
      future: _getItem,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
        List<GetItems> _item = snapshot.data;
        return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
          height: 250,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 20,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/img/' + _item[0].imagens),
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              )),
        );
      },
    ),
```

Comment: Funcionou! obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente o seu Widget está sendo construído mais rápido do que o tempo de resposta da API, e seu `initState` não espera uma resposta da API. É para isso que existe o [FutureBuilder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ek8ZPdWj4Qo) você precisa mostrar uma tela de carregamento ou "nada" enquanto os seus dados estiverem carregando, uma vez carregados você pode atualizar o estado do seu Widget com a lista de dados carregadas.

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: _getItem,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
      if(snapshot.hasError){
        /// Terminou de carregar mas com erro
      } else {
        /// Tudo ok mostre a sua lista que está dentro snapshot.data
      }
    } else {
      /// carregando informações
    }
  },
),
```

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado.